# Next js app deployed to heroku does not work

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I just deployed my Nextjs app to Heroku along with Yoga-GraphQL server and encounter a problem. The problem is that after deploying my app doesn't work further than login page. All other routes as `/signup` or `/requestPasswordReset` do not work either.

I tried to find out the reason by `heroku logs --tail`. It logs messages like these

```
2019-07-11T08:25:34.301170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/" host=site-app-prod.herokuapp.com request_id=2d559e57-80ea-433f-af0f-224ed70da623 fwd="119.224.101.31" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=204 bytes=301 protocol=https
2019-07-11T08:25:34.613380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=site-app-prod.herokuapp.com request_id=7bd566a1-8d9a-426c-815a-a59d38b94341 fwd="119.224.101.31" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=202 protocol=https
```

so everything seems to be fine on that side.

I also switched off CORS as it threw errors.

Are there any ideas why it can be so?

Comment: did you create Procfile before upload project and deploy and what is contained of it?

Comment: @Ashok, no, but I did include `heroku-postbuild` hook to compile my app

Comment: And what about your enviroment variable ?